# How to completely restrict the modification of properties of a const object

Tags: javascript

Even after using strict mode, I am able to update the object variable.
How is possible? Is it possible to create constant objects at all?

```
"use strict";

const x = {a:"sss"}
x.a = "k"
console.log(x)
```

outputs:

```
{ a: 'k' }
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)  _"The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned."_

Comment: @abhishekkannojia: Thanks for pointing out - I found the same but also found this easy fix online for the same (refer the answer).

Comment: @torazaburo: u are right but the way i started this question was different and i didn't know much about the behavior then so i didn't search by the title specified in the question.

Comment: Also, the question i asked is more specific to the behavior of the objects and properties specific scenario while the one you mentioned is a more generic question. Its kind of tough to call this as duplicate even if the question is a subset of it. Its hard to search for such questions if the problems cases differ.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to find duplicates some times. You'd probably have had better luck if your searches had included the word "variable", instead of "const object" as you used in your title--when you use `const`, you are applying that to a **variable**, not whatever object or value the variable happens to hold. I do think it is almost an exact dup, because it explicitly discusses the objects/properties issue you mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay - so it is required to use Object.freeze call t make the object unchangeable.
Even the strict mode isn't required.

```
const x = {a:"sss"}
Object.freeze(x);

x.a = "k"
console.log(x)
```

Outputs:

```
x.a = "k"
    ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'a' of object '#<Object>'
```

Answer (score 5):

**ES6** `const` is not about **immutability**.

`const` only creates a read-only reference and that means that you cannot reassign another value for the object.

`const` creates an immutable `binding` and guarantees that no `rebinding` will happen.

Using an `assignment operator` on a **const** variable throws a **TypeError** exception:

Short example:

```js
const x = {a:"sss"}
x={a:"k"}
console.log(x)
```

You will see the following message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

Comment: Thanks @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai for pointing out